# Balancing the stack

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-pointer

If I setup the stack like this

```
push rbp;
mov rbp, rsp;
sub rsp, 64;
```

do I need to

```
mov rsp, rbp;
pop rbp;
ret 64;
```

or only

```
mov rsp, rbp;
pop rbp;
ret;
```

?

Comment: The first one (with `ret 64`) is deallocating stack space set up by the caller. That's how `stdcall` gets rid of arguments on the stack. But here it would just be destroying something.

Comment: @harold How can I reserve some space without destroying arguments on the stack?

Comment: @harold Or maybe a better question is: Can I use [rbp - from-8-to-64] without worrying?

Comment: Generally yes, unless you're writing something bigger than 8 bytes of course

Comment: Isn't that 64 bytes of reserved stack? Or its 64 bits?

Comment: 64 bytes, and you can use all 64 of them, the problem with something larger than 8 bytes is that if you wrote it at, say `rbp - 8`, it would extend past the area you allocated. Similarly, for things that are less wide, there are slightly more places you could use, for example you can use `rbp - 64` through `rbp - 1` as places to store bytes.

Comment: @harold So when I write ```mov [rbp - 8], rax;```, I'm moving the value of RAX into my first 8-bytes stack variable. That instruction isn't taking any more space than 8 bytes on the stack, right?

Comment: Right, that's perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to do:

```
mov rsp, rbp;
pop rbp;
ret;
```

As it will restore the old value of rsp ( regardless of how much was decreased in the `sub` instruction ).

Comment: Btw, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO let's me do it (18min remaining)

Answer (score 2):

The second one, if you are going to use the C calling convention (caller removes the arguments).

```
mov rsp, rbp;
pop rbp;
ret;
```

If you would use the first epilog, this is what happens with your stack:

```
push rbp;     ;RSP = RSP - 8  (1)  |
mov rbp, rsp; ;Keep RSP (2)        | Your prologue. Nothing wrong here.
sub rsp, 64;  ;RSP = RSP - 64      |
...
...
mov rsp, rbp; ;Retrieve RSP from (2)
pop rbp;      ;RSP = RSP + 8. Now it's at the same address as before (1)
ret 64;       ;Return, but after that, add 64 to RSP
```

So when this function returns to its caller, the stack pointer is 64 bytes ahead of its position just before the `CALL` to this function. This is fine, if your function is defined with the STD calling convention (callee removes the arguments). I think that this is not what you want, as you seem to think that the ret 64 is for restoring the 64 bytes the stack allocated for automatic variables.

Comment: In fact, this code will replace a syscall in the Linux kernel. What are the assumptions there? Who must care about the parameters?

Comment: You may want to check the chosen answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520778/why-doesnt-linux-follow-unix-syscall-conventions